# Registering the google api key for publishing app

Tags: android, api-key

When we are ready to publish your application,we must get a Maps API Key that is based on the certificate that be will used to sign the application for release n  then change the Maps API Key strings referenced by all of  MapView elements, so that they reference the new Key.

But my problem is how to get the api key for publishing based on the certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Google Map to visible in all Devices after you launched your app in Android Market  you need to create Keystore using Release Key.

Check my post for creating [Signed Application and Register Map using Release Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key/7445030#7445030)