# Android Maps API Key Issues

Tags: android

I am having a weird problem with a simple map application I am trying to write (API 2.2). Yesterday, I started the app and I could see the map displayed and was able to pan around and zoom in and out. It worked perfectly. I also ran the app successfully on a Galaxy tab (I normally run them on an emulator). Today, I started the application, but instead of seeing the map, I see a grid of grey boxes. I thought it might be a problem with the API key, so I created a second one and swapped it with the first, this did not fix the problem.

The only difference between the times I tried running the projects was that I did it on two different computers. It worked originally on the computer that I created the project on, but it now will no longer work on any computer that I have attempted to use. I don't know that this is related, but it is the only significant thing that changed between when I ran the project each time.

After looking through the LogCat, I have found two errors that might be relevant to my problem they are:

Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
 Couldn't get connection factory client

Does anyone know if these are problems, and if so, how to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making the Map View to visible in all Device you need to Sign application using Release key and put your Key in Xml :

Check this for generating [Release Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key/7445030#7445030).

Comment: I tried this, but still no luck. However, I'm glad you posted how to generate the release key, that had me stumped too. Thanks.

Comment: @ninjamast3r It's working copy what i tried.. Double check the process.If you need any doubt lemme know??

Comment: I copied the steps exactly as you did them, but it has not changed the result. I have not tested the new APK on a physical device yet however.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is related. The api key that is used uses your computers randomly generated debug key to sign the application. On a different computer you will have a different debug key. This key is automatically used to sign your applications when you run them. You should use the export tool to create a new key that you can put on multiple computers. Just right click on your project and click export and follow the instructions. You will need to update the api key with Google for the new signing key that you generate.

Comment: I have inserted the new signing key, but I still see the grey grid when I run the app in my emulator. The same errors are also still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The map API key is generated based on the debug key which will be different for different computers.
(This is precisely why if you try to install the app from eclipse in one machine then try to reinstall it on another machine you get the error that the app requires manual uninstallation)

So you need to generate one maps API key per development environment and register all of them in the developer console.

Hope this helped.