# Map is not displaying in phone only black screen

Tags: android, google-maps

The following errors i m getting when the Map app is running in phone. 
I create both debug key and custom apiKey  using eclipse,

Right click on project->Android tools->Export signed application package and then fill the form and then using keytool i got the MD5  and then apiKey.

I also replace the debug apikey with custom apiKey. 
How to sort out these errors?

```
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971): IllegalStateException on drawMap. Wiping cache.
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null Bitmap! "loading_tile"; if seen during a test, this usually means that the image file needs to be added to the test.config file
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.common.graphics.android.AndroidImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.common.graphics.android.AndroidImageFactory.createImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.createTempImages(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.getTempImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.getImage(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
11-01 17:00:08.238: ERROR/MapView(8971):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my post for creating Signed Application so that Map View will shown in all Devices and Emulators :

[Post for Map View Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key/7445030#7445030)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your icons exists in the drawable folder, which were actually used as the application logo.

Comment: @ Mohan it 1.the errors appear while debugging in phone               2.icons exist in drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the map key for the custom apiKey?

I think you did not change that.

Change the map key.
Use http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html to get a new map key with the custom certificate's MD5 fingerprint.

Comment: Android 2.1 and 1.5 \ 1.6 are different, under the system files, the system built-in google map corresponding to the packet size is not the same! So it can run on 1.5 or 1.6  but on 2.1 may not be able to run it !.Btw are you using any custom rom?

Comment: No.not a custom rom.but phone is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Signe your apk and install in on real device by using Export from Eclipse ,it will work.