# Mapview not showing map when run from Eclipse. How to sign the app?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mapview, apk

If I export the project to APK and sign the app with my key, the MapView works on my cellphone. But not when I run the app on my cellphone by selecting Run in  Eclipse.

I think this is because it is not signed with my key. I looked at the project settings, but I could not find any options to sign the app to run it.

I cannot export it all the time just to debug/run the app. What are my options? Is it impossible to get MapView working if I run it from Eclipse's Run menu?

Possible solutions could be

- Is there any way to sign the app for Run/Debug automatically?
- Is    there any option to get MapView working without signing for
  Run/Debug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a bit annoying.  When you run the app from eclipse it is being signed by the debug.keystore.  I recommend commenting out your api key and then put the api key for the debug.keystore and then when you want to run out of eclipse switch it back out.  See link below for more info on the debug.keystore.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I searched the Internet and found the solution while I was waiting for the answers.

It turned out to be, that a debug certificate was automatically generated and used by Eclipse and I had to create another key for that certificate. To get that, I had to type a lengthy command.

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
> ~typingcat/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

I think this is a problem with Linuxphiles, not-so-user-friendly. There could be millions of people typing that. Why can't they just provide a simple GUI....

Comment: Yeah I would just store both keys, one for running from eclipse and one for the signed apk.  It isn't the best solution, but worked pretty well for me.