# Does each developer needs its own Google Map Api-key?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api, api-key

I just started to play around with the Google map api in Android.
I did generate my *MD5 certificate fingerprint* on **debug.keystore** as explained in 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey
and later generated the Api key with this link:
http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

It is working well as expected.
But the problem is that we are a couple of different programmers that share the same code base and it seems weird that each programmer should create its own key and change the xml file in order to get it to work.

***Is there any way to create a more global key for the google map API that can be shared among developers?***

Using Google API console https://code.google.com/apis/console
, I also created a key for Google Map API, and added the other programmer to the project as team members, but that code does not seem to work. not even for me! ***What is the difference between the first API code and this code? which one should be used?***

Thanks for any explanations

Comment: look at this once :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key