# android Google Map doesn't load inside TabHost

Tags: android, google-maps

after few days of freaking out and ugh frustrate thinking my API key is wrong, i found out that my MapView will load in my application only when its the main content of the screen.

Every time I'm trying to attach it to a TabHost or trying to load it through `getDecorView()` inside an already exist view, the map doesn't load and i get a blank map only.

it is really important for me to use in a TabHost.

Does someone have an idea how to fix it or why it's happening ?

Comment: Is the activity containing your `TabHost` a `MapActivity`? If not, there is your problem.

Comment: you are defiantly my SUPER HERO ! Write this as an answer so i could accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity that, in the end, hosts a `MapView` *must* be a `MapActivity`, at least in the current incarnation of the Maps add-on for Android.

This can cause confusion, or outright problems, where you are trying to have the activity be something else.

For example, some people try to use a `TabActivity`, and use activities as the contents of tabs. That is officially deprecated now, and IMHO was never an especially good model in the first place. When it comes to maps, even if the activity you try loading into the tab is a `MapActivity`, that does not really matter -- the activity *containing the tabs* must be a `MapActivity`. The common workaround is to use `TabHost` and `TabWidget` in a `MapActivity`. While this does require a call to `setup()` on the `TabHost`, and you lose some helper methods, it gets past this problem.