# android how to load an intent inside a view

Tags: android, activitygroup

i know that `ActivityGroup` is able to change the content of a view, but it is about to be decaperate..

and i don't really like `Fragment`.. is there a way that i can built some kind of my own `TabHost` ?
a button that will change the content of a specific view ?

i don't want to use TabHost because i have 4 buttons which only 2 of them should run a new intent, and the other 2 use `Dialogs`..

i can manipulate the `TabHost` that only 2 tabs will run an intent and the other will lunch a `Dialog` but i think that not the right way..

any ideas ?

Comment: Use fragments. Not liking fragments is just rowing against the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of putting an activity inside an activity is what was deprecated. `ActivityGroup` and its subclasses implemented that pattern, though it was always optional (e.g., `TabHost` never required you to put activities in tabs). You are welcome to either:

- just use views
- use fragments
- use activities inside of activities and hope that "deprecated" does not turn into "flat out will not run" in the future

I strongly encourage you to choose one of the first two items.

Comment: But if i understand correctly, mapview wont work well with fragment doesnt it? On android 2.3

Comment: @AsafNevo: A `MapView` must go in a `MapActivity`, and so it cannot go in a `FragmentActivity` using the fragment backport. However, it's not like having activities-in-tabs would help you any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331063/android-google-map-doesnt-load-inside-tabhost/12331188#12331188

Comment: It will help me because i can extend MapActivity in my tabhost class and than the map will work perfectly

Comment: @AsafNevo: Yes, you can have a `MapActivity` hold a `TabHost`. Your tab containing a map will use a `MapView` as the content of the tab. This corresponds with the first bullet in my list above.