# Google Maps Are not Showing under Tabwidget otherwise works perfectly

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, tabwidget

The Activity in which i have my google maps implimentation works perfectly when i run it directly but when i try to use that activity under tabwidgets, instead of maps it only show grey Gridlines.
Can't figure it out why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

After Visting many post finally found the solution, as in this post

[android Google Map doesn't load inside TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331063/android-google-map-doesnt-load-inside-tabhost)

which explains clearly that why we could not load fragments inside tabhost instead we should use FragmentTabHost.

To Implement FragmentTabHost follow this post :
http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/