# Google map not showing on android (signed apk) with Google V2 release key

Tags: android, google-maps, signed

I am exactly following step [Given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/one-google-maps-key-for-all-developers/7445030#7445030).
API key is obtained by following steps [Here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:1035109673277)
i already upload the apk on market for test purpose but still its not showing map although it display map with debug key.but when i try to use release Google map key its showing white screen with zoomin and zoomout button but no maps.

[Google play store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.map.test.one&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tYXAudGVzdC5vbmUiXQ..)

MapFragment

```
public class CustomMap extends SupportMapFragment {

private static final int ZOOMIN_ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

public static CustomMap newInstance() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap();
    customMap.setArguments(bundle);
    return customMap;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    GoogleMap googleMap = getMap();
    if (googleMap == null) {
    } else {
        LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(70.00,
                33.00);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Title")
                .snippet("Address")
                .position(mLatLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10),
                ZOOMIN_ANIMATION_DURATION, null);
    }
}
```

}

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    class="com.example.maptest.CustomMap" 
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.baresso.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.baresso.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDcAy3bEVhv_lhAH1hHNHk_RpvyXiN0xNI" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Will not work with the latest change in their policies which limits the usage of google map libraries  directly.

To solve this either you have to include entire google maps as a third party plug in  or you can display the google map in an webview and pass locations through a javascript html function.

for ex:--

```
<script>
function initialize()
{
document.getElementById('dummyDIV').innerHTML = '<div id="googleMap"     
style="width:'+screen.width+'px;height:'+screen.height+'px;"></div>';
var sURL1 = window.document.URL;
var sURL2 =sURL1.split("%20");
var sURL= sURL2[0];
for (j=1;j<sURL2.length;j++){
    sURL = sURL+' '+sURL2[j];
} 

var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(19.155721,72.856025),
  zoom:10,
  disableDefaultUI:true, 
  zoomControl:true,
  mapTypeControl:true,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


   if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
{
var bifurcatedURL = sURL.split("?");    

var everyMarker = bifurcatedURL[1].split("&");  
for (i=0;i<everyMarker.length;i++)
    {
        var markerDetails =everyMarker[i].split("+");
        var lat = (markerDetails[0]);
        var lon = (markerDetails[1]);
        var address =markerDetails[2];
        var type = markerDetails[3];
        var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        map.setCenter(markerPosition);
        if(type=='a'||type=='A')
    var marker=new 
google.maps.Marker({position:markerPosition,icon:'atm_marker.png'});
        else if(type=='b'||type=='B')
 var marker=new google.maps.Marker
 ({position:markerPosition,icon:'branch_marker.png'});
        else if(type=='c'||type=='C')
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:markerPosition,icon:'pin_blue.png'});

            marker.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new             google.maps.InfoWindow({content:address});
            listenMarker(marker,address,infowindow,map)
    }
}   
}

function listenMarker (marker,address,infowindow,map)
{
// so marker is associated with the closure created for the listenMarker function call
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: this  is really pathetic. :(
why google map V2 not working on android plateform ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Its is written clearly here that it will distributed as a part of google play services SDK from now on .. 

The are now following approach used by Bing & Apple.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

> 1. I think the problem is with the Obtaining an API Key Or With The SHA-1  Finger Print.
> 2. have You Give the application Package with the SHA-1 fingerprint in the 
>      [Google Consol](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)
> 3. install Google Play Service into Your Emulator or Android Device.
> 4. Please prefer Android Device for Map Testing .

Answer (score 0):

problem's lying here

```
<permission
android:name="com.baresso.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

replace it with giving your own package name..

```
<permission
android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

**and here**

replace this

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.baresso.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
with <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: This permission is now completely unnecessary. Google Play Services v3.1.59 made it useless.  https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/Dk65EACXqsh

Answer (score 0):

copy SHA1 from logcat when you siged your apk click on finish and add this on your google play developer console project  SHA-1 certificate fingerprint this will show your map with signeg apk