# Map is not showing after releasing app

Tags: android, google-maps

after releasing the app, map is not showing.please any one help me. I followed many steps in stack overflow but i did not getting any correct answer

Comment: You have to provide the SHa  fingerprint of your signed apk file rather that your machine`s code, at google dev console.

Answer (score 5):

For Google Map to visible in all Devices after you launched your app in Android Market you need to create Keystore using Release Key.

Check this post for creating [Signed Application and Register Map using Release Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/one-google-maps-key-for-all-developers/7445030#7445030)

Comment: Thank you @Ronak joshi but if need to check before launching my app in Android market how can i know whether my map is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

copy signed apk in your device and install it...!

Comment: i already tried to copy the sighed apk and install in my device still is not working. what steps i need to follow? i put the api key in both release and debug xml file.is this enough or i need to do anything else?